# Use jQuery to find a <tr> that is after a row with specific atribute in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

I don't know if the Title of this post makes sense, but here's a sample of what I'm working with:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="classRow" bgcolor="#EFE5D3" style="font-weight: bold;">
        <td width="35px"><a class="classEditLink" name="33" href="#">Edit</a></td>
        <td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" class="chkSelectToDelete" name="deleteClasses[]" value="33" /></td>
        <td>CLASS1234</td>
        <td>Class description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="classDocsRow noDocs">
        <td colspan="4">
            <strong>No documents are currently associated with this class.</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to remove the second row by finding it using the previous row's first `<td>`'s `<a>`'s name attribute. The psuedo code would be something like

```
$('.classRow a[name="' + classID + '"]').parent().parent().next().remove()
```

I don't know if that's proper jQuery syntax (as is, it doesn't work), but hopefully you get the point: the "starting point" of the selector is the name attribute of the `<a>` tag and I need to remove the following row. The `<a>` tag's name attribute is the only unique attribute in a given `<tbody>` on the page (not inlcuding the third and fourth `<td>`s in that row, but you get the point).

What is a properly formatted/syntaxed jQuery selector to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
$('tr:has(a[name="33"]) + tr').remove();
```

Links to the corresponding JQuery documentation:

- [`:has()` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)
- [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- [Next Adjacent Selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel - that worked when I put that in before my $.ajax() call - I think I have something else going on that's preventing it from working where I need it.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, then you want something like this:

`$(".classRow a[name=" + className + "]").closest("tr").next().remove();`

See an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2FKjg/1/).

Comment: use single quotes for external wrapping :D

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$('.classRow a[name="' + classID + '"]').parents("tr").next().remove();
```

if it doesn't work please alert the classID to check if it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Your sample works, just make sure that classID is set: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eHgv/)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't necessarily answer your question directly, but just a word of advice...   If you have a table listing classes in each row, then it makes more sense to put everything about each individual class within the same row.  So, the documents container really belongs within the class row that the documents are associated with.

The benefits to that are:

- Semantic meaning and relationship association
- Much easier way to reference parent/sibling/child elements

Then all you'd have to do is something like this:

```
$('.classRow a[name="' + classID + '"]').parent('classRow').find('.classDocs').remove();
```

Comment: If I understand your point, Kon, I originally had it that way in the form of a nested table for the class's docs within the class row. That became a jQuery (and PHP) nightmare (at least for this jQuery/PHP noob). After a code rewite that put each class and its associated docs in separate <tbody> tags it became much easier to manage for me.

Comment: To each his/her own.  In general though, you want to build a structure that makes more sense.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me (tested on your HTML above):

```
$('.classRow a[name="' + classID + '"]')
    .closest('tr')
    .next()
    .remove();
```

Also I'm not sure exactly where this code is executed in your example, but if it's supposed to happen "on load" you need to wait for the DOM to be ready:

```
$(function() {
    // the code snippet here
});
```

Comment: Nope, it's acutally within the "success" part of an $.ajax() call to a php script that deletes the doc record from the database.